# CATiledLayer Drop Shadow Rendering Incorrect

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-animation

I have a view that's rendering a PDF into a CATiledLayer.  This is working well.

Now I'm attempting to add a drop shadow to the view, so I did the usual:

```
    tiledLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
    tiledLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
    tiledLayer.shadowRadius = 5;
    tiledLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    tiledLayer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;
```

But what I'm seeing rendered is incorrect.  What seems to be happening is that there's a drop shadow drawn for each tile as the tiles are being drawn.  Once all the tiles are drawn, the final product looks right and has a shadow in the right place, but the intermediate rendering is distracting.

How can I use a drop shadow with a CATiledLayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your CATiledLayer in a container layer with those shadow attributes applied to it. Judging by the `self.bounds` call, you might already be embedding the CATiledLayer in a view’s layer, in which case (unless you need `masksToBounds`) you can just apply the shadow attributes to that layer directly.

Answer (score -1):

It makes perfect sense that a drop shadow is being drawn for each tile, that is exactly what you told it to do. I assume you have your tiles loading in some kind of parent view that contains them (usually a UIScrollView). You should set your drop shadow on that containing view.

Comment: Have you used CATiledLayer? It doesn’t represent a single tile—it draws its contents *as* tiles.

Comment: I have, I use them for PDF rendering in an app. From the sounds of this applying the shadow to each tile does not seem right, I may not be completely clear but what I am understanding from the OPs post is he is seeing a drop shadow rendered as each tile is created. But what he really wants is his entire tiled area to have a drop shadow, I would imagine applying the drop shadow to the containing view's layer would yield these affect. The answer you've posted sounds like a very similar approach. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the “exactly what you told it to do”. How does the behavior described make sense when he's giving it a shadow path of the containing view’s bounds?

Comment: Fair enough, I misunderstood CATiledLayer I think.